# How do I add a second Git repository to my VS Code editor's source version control

Tags: github, version-control, visual-studio-code

How do I add an instance of GitHub Enterprise as a Source Control Provider to my Visual Studio Code editor?  I already have my editor configured for my personal GitHub repository.  I need my editor to work with both my personal GitHub repository and my company project's GitHub Enterprise repository.